# Dynamically create inheriting object with name from external source

Tags: python, ui-automation, squish

**What I'm Trying to do**

Considering a file with rows:

```
A B C value
A B D value
```

Is it possible to create a structure that would be able to acccess the values like this:

```
A.B.C.val()
A.B.D.val()
```

Considering that `A, B, C, D` are containers (like forms, windows, etc), I would like to be able to get each element path by using this structure.

**What I'm asking**

In the end, what I would want to know is if, having a class (let's say `generic`), can I create an inheriting class named `A` (name read from a file, can be anything) during runtime which would then cease to exist (the last part is not really important)?

Comment: I'm really having a hard time understanding what the last paragraph here has to do with the rest of the stuff you've written.  Do you think you can make a slightly more concrete example?

Comment: The first part is what I'm trying to do, then I thought about it and just asked something that would get me what I want to try it. I kept the first part just to see if anyone thinks it's just stupid or has done it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
# Generic class definition
class Generic (object):
    value = None
    @classmethod
    def val(cls):
        return int(cls.value)

# Top level class
TopLevelClass = type('TopLevelClass',
                     (Generic, ), {})

lines = ["A B C 42",
         "A B D 43"]

for line in lines:
    # Parse the line
    path = line.split()[:-1]
    value = line.split()[-1]
    # Create the classes
    current = TopLevelClass
    for x in path:
        if hasattr(current,x):
            current = getattr(current,x)
        else:
            cls = type(x, (Generic, ), {})
            setattr(current,x,cls)
            current = cls
    # Apply value
    setattr(cls,'value',value)


# Test
print(TopLevelClass.A.B.C.val())
print(TopLevelClass.A.B.D.val())
```

Output :

```
>>> 42
>>> 43
```

Comment: seems right. I will check it and let you know. 
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I just edited my answer to handle several lines, please check it out